# Passing parameters with flask render_template()

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, ajax, flask

I need to display some select options. Once the category is chosen, I want to display the subcategory with another select.

My flask code

```
def return_panim():
    panim = ["", "טיפול ניקוי עמוק", "טיפול יופי", "טיפול פילינג עמוק", "טיפול לאקנה ולעור בעייתי", "טיפול אנטי אייג'ינג מזוטרפיה", "טיפול אנטי אייג'ינג מיצוק העור"]
    data = """
        <label>קטגוריה</label>
        <select id="subCategory" onchange="loadDoc()">"""
    for pan in panim:
        data = data + '<option value=' + '"' + pan + '"' + ">" + '"' + pan + '"' + '</option>'
    data = data + '</select>'
    return data


def return_categories():
    category_list = ["", "טיפול פנים", "טיפול הסרת שיער", "טיפול הסרת פיגמנטציה", "עיצוב גבות", "מניקור", "פדיקור", "שעווה", "שעווה גברים"]
    data = """
        <label>תת קטגוריה</label>
        <select id="category" onchange="loadDoc()">"""
    for category in category_list:
        data = data + '<option value=' + '"' + category + '"' + '>' + category + '</option>'
    data = data + "</select>"    
    return data

@app.route("/appoint", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def apple(name=None):
    if request.method == "POST":
        r = request.get_data().decode("utf-8")
        print(r)
        if r ==  "טיפול פנים":
            print(return_panim())
            return render_template("appoint.html",  data_category=return_categories(), data_subcategory=return_panim())
    return render_template("appoint.html",  data_category=return_categories())
```

My client side

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
{{ data_category | safe }}
{{ data_subcategory | safe }}
<script>
  function loadDoc() {
    let encoder = new TextEncoder();
  const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var sel = document.getElementById("category");
  var text = sel.value;
  xhttp.open("POST", "https://www.annastudio.beauty/appoint", true);
  xhttp.send(encoder.encode(text));
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I try to return without condition like so

```
@app.route("/appoint", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def apple(name=None):
    return render_template("appoint.html",  data_category=return_categories(), data_subcategory=return_panim())
```

It renders both selects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you have to use Ajax for this task.

The following example uses two field sets. The second field set is enabled or disabled with JavaScript depending on the selection made in the first select element. A disabled field set is hidden using CSS.

If you don't want to use a field set, you can disable and enable individual input fields in the same way.

```py
from enum import Enum, unique
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    redirect, 
    render_template, 
    request
)

@unique 
class Categories(str, Enum):
    OPTION1 = "טיפול פנים"
    OPTION2 = "טיפול הסרת שיער"
    OPTION3 = "טיפול הסרת פיגמנטציה"
    OPTION4 = "עיצוב גבות"
    OPTION5 = "מניקור"
    OPTION6 = "פדיקור"
    OPTION7 = "שעווה"
    OPTION8 = "שעווה גברים"

@unique 
class SubCategories(str, Enum):
    OPTION1 = "טיפול ניקוי עמוק"
    OPTION2 = "טיפול יופי"
    OPTION3 = "טיפול פילינג עמוק"
    OPTION4 = "טיפול לאקנה ולעור בעייתי"
    OPTION5 = "טיפול אנטי אייג'ינג מזוטרפיה"
    OPTION6 = "טיפול אנטי אייג'ינג מיצוק העור"

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/appoint', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def appoint():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        category = request.form.get('category', Categories.OPTION1, type=lambda x: Categories[x])
        subcategory = request.form.get('subcategory', type=lambda x: SubCategories[x])
        print(category.value)
        print(subcategory and subcategory.value)
        return redirect(request.url)
    return render_template(
        'appoint.html', 
        categories=Categories, 
        subcategories=SubCategories
    )
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Appoint</title>
    <style>
        fieldset[disabled] {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    
    <form method="post">
        <fieldset name="basics">
            <label for="category">Category</label>
            <select name="category" id="category">
                {% for cat in categories -%}
                <option value="{{ cat.name }}">{{ cat.value }}</option>
                {% endfor -%}
            </select>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset name="extended">
            <label for="subcategory">Subcategory</label>
            <select name="subcategory" id="subcategory">
                {% for cat in subcategories -%}
                <option value="{{ cat.name }}">{{ cat.value }}</option>
                {% endfor -%}
            </select>
        </fieldset>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <script>
        (function() {

            const triggerVal = {{ categories.OPTION1.name | tojson }};
            const selectElem = document.getElementById('category');
            const fieldsetElem = document.querySelector('fieldset[name="extended"]');
            selectElem.addEventListener('change', function() {
                fieldsetElem.disabled = this.value !== triggerVal;
            });

        })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```